# Central limit theorem and standard normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

In [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) you can find the next text:
[image]

If n is large enough then a variance should be around 0 but not 1?

Comment: Haven't you missed spotting the $1/\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator...?

Comment: @Xi'an you are right. Xn ~ Normal(true_mean, true_variance/n)?